# Slide Gesture and Pinch in iOS 6 disables javascript animations

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios6, responsive-design

I have a responsive design bootstrap based website -- http://joyasolutions.com that works correctly in iOS 5* - but after I upgraded iOS to 6.0.1 on my iPad - there is now a wiggle that makes the slide gesture practically useless and if either try to slide or pinch to set the size - all slider animations including all buttons no longer work.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?